# Assistance needed with powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying the execute the powershell script found at :

https://github.com/amanbedi18/Azure-KeyVault-Automation/tree/master/UploadSecrets

https://github.com/amanbedi18/Azure-KeyVault-Automation

This script is used to automate upload of secrets to azure key-vault.

I have created the below json file and named it **/user/kv/AzureSecretsMetaData.json**

```
[
{
    "key":  "test1",
    "value":  "1"
},
{
    "key":  "test2",
    "value":  "2"
}
]
```

I then copied contents of setKeyVaultSecrets.ps1 to **/user/kv/setKeyVaultSecrets.ps1**

I have tried the below commands that were mentioned in the readme and powershell script files and get the below errors, could someone please help me execute this script correctly and point out what I am doing wrong here.

**./setkeyVaultSecret.ps1 -KeyVaultName 'avkv01'**

```
setkeyVaultSecret.ps1: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

**./setkeyVaultSecret.ps1 -KeyVaultName 'avkv01' -KVSecretMetadataFilePath '/home/aditya/kv/AzureSecretsMetaData.json'**

```
setkeyVaultSecret.ps1: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are scripts you found, they are very poorly written and I would advise not using them.  I would suggest installing the az powershell module and using those scripts as a reference in writing your own script.  You can install the az powershell module with powershellget:

```
Install-module az -force -allowclobber
```

The way the script that you are trying to call is written very strangely.  It defines two different parameter sets, but each of the two parameters are mandatory for BOTH parameter sets?!  That doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you must run them, you will probably need to modify them a bit.  They don't really seem finished..  Why not modify the script and get rid of the parameter sets altogether?  Also, the example in the script indicates that the "$KVSecretMetadataFilePath" parameter is not mandatory, since it is not being called, but is defined as being mandatory when defining your parameter.  You need to make clear if this parameter is required or not.  If it is required  Make it look more like this:

```
    <#

.PREREQUISITE
1. An Azure key vault and its name as parameter.
2. Json template should be properly populated with valid json schema in sampleSecretValues.json in KeyVaultjson directory.

.PARAMETER vaultName
The name of the key vault.

.EXAMPLE
. setKeyVaultSecret.ps1 -KeyVaultName 'somekeyvault'
#>

# provision keys and secrets to a key vault 

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $KeyVaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $KVSecretMetadataFilePath
)

Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force 
Import-Module Azure -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Import-Module AzureRM.Resources

Set-StrictMode -Version 3

$json = Get-Content $KVSecretMetadataFilePath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$json | ForEach {

$secretToSearch = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $_.key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($secretToSearch -ne $null)
{
    echo "The secret $_.key already exists !"
}
Else
{
    $NewSecret = Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $_.key -SecretValue (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.value -AsPlainText -Force ) -Verbose
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Source Vault Resource Id: "$(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName).ResourceId
}
}
```

If it is not required, remove the line "[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]" above the $KVSecretMetadataFilePath declaration.